# Estimating difficulty of instances of NP problems

Tags: complexity-theory, bitcoin

NP problems look like they are suitable for use as trapdoor functions or proofs of work, since they are difficult to solve, but easy to verify. Unfortunately, they seem a little hard to use in adversarial settings where an opponent can control problem selection because while worst-case problems are NP, particular instances can be solved very quickly.

So: is there any algorithm which can take instances and estimate - more efficiently than trying to solve them - how hard or close to worst-case they are?

(The context is musing about a Bitcoin protocol where the proofs-of-work were reusable and not useless hash checks. The obvious approach is to have a central authority issue, for each transaction block, a NP instance which corresponds to a real-world problem. But the central authority could be subverted, and start issuing easy problems which would render the network vulnerable to double-spends. One could accept problems from multiple authorities, or anyone, but the chosen-easy problem remains. If there were some way to *estimate* the difficulty of any problem presented to the network, then 'too easy' problems could simply be ignored, falling back to the hash race if necessary.)

EDIT: jaxtr links me to ["Predicting Satisfiability at the Phase Transition"](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~kevinlb/papers/2012-PredictingSatisfiability.pdf), which gives algorithms which estimate hardness at 70% accuracy - but they don't seem to investigate whether the algorithm can be deliberately fooled. (As well, one can apparently generate SAT problems with specified probabilities of being satisfiable.)

Answer (score 4):

This is the same problem faced by researchers trying to create public-key encryption algorithms based on np-completeness. As far as I know, there are some stabs at it, but it's still an open problem. See the discussion here: [Are there public key cryptography algorithms that are provably NP-hard to defeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/311064)

I know I've seen more recent work, but can't find it offhand. I recall a book composed of articles about alternative cryptosystems should factorization suddenly become cheap, and I'll try to dig up the link.

**Edit**: The comment below points to the book I was thinking of. [The website](http://pqcrypto.org/) has lots of good references to various relevant papers. See the "code based" section in particular.

Comment: [Post-Quantum Cryptography](http://www.amazon.com/Post-Quantum-Cryptography-Daniel-J-Bernstein/dp/3540887016) by DJB et al.?

Comment: Mikhail: Yep, that's the one I was thinking of. Thanks!